# Custom thread in JAX-WS web method

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-ws

I have a problem with web service via JAX-WS. If I start thread in web method, it will be ended while connection with client ended.

Example:

```
@WebMethod(operationName="test")
public boolean test()
{
  Thread th = new MyThread();
  th.start();
  // Thread is running
  ...
  return true;
  // Now thread th ends;
}
```

Is there any solution to keep thread th running?

Comment: i think i misunderstood your question.  you _want_ the thread to keep running after the method returns?  if so, you don't have to do anything, the thread will keep going until it completes.

Comment: It isn't true, try it. Thread forcely ends when web method returns.

Comment: are you running this in an app server?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are trying to start a Thread on a Java EE app server.  Manual threading is in violation of the Java EE specs, which is why you are running into problems.  on some app servers you can't even *start* a separate thread at all.  From the spec:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage thread groups.These functions are reserved for the EJB container. Allowing the enterprise bean to manage threads would decrease the container’s ability to properly manage the runtime environment.

If you need to do the work on a separate thread, you need to use the facilities provided by the app server for asynchronous work.  some options are queueing the data to a JMS queue for processing by an MDB or possibly using an asynchronous ejb request (think that's in Java EE 6).

Comment: Might help if you quoted from the spec or some other source

Comment: @kolossus - because you don't believe me or because you don't want to look it up yourself?

Comment: Lol, no. Because it'll help if someone else hit this link. It's generally advisable(correct me if i'm wrong) to include actual content from your sources here because links die, sources change, APIs get deprecated. Won't have +1'd you if i didn't **believe**

Comment: it is generally advisable.  if you have that link handy, i'll gladly include it.

Comment: `The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise
bean must not attempt to manage thread groups.These functions are reserved for the EJB container. Allowing the enterprise bean to manage threads would decrease the container’s ability to properly manage the runtime environment.`                                                       From the Spec about EJB's (which I **believe** should apply to all managed objects)

Comment: @kolossus - thanks, added.  yes, this applies to pretty much all managed objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be sure before returning that the thread has finished - easiest way is th.join(). This method waits for the thread to die.

Comment: Yes, but algorithm in th is very time-consuming and should be running independently, so client can't wait for 'return'.

Comment: OP is not trying to wait for the thread, but trying to get it to run past the initial method invocation.  (question is a bit confusing).